# Ensuring Completion of Operations During app Termination in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, concurrency, persistence, lifecycle

Let's say we have a Flutter app where we want to save some persistent data using shared preferences.

(We don't want to save the data persistently every time the user changes it because the UI depends directly on the data, and in order to save it we need to use await async, and that lags the UI), so we use WidgetsBindingObserver to detect when the app goes to the background in order to use that event as an efficient catch-all opportunity to save the data.

So, we have some code like this in the root page of our app:

```
@override
void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
    super.didChangeAppLifecycleState(state);
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.paused) {
      // went to Background
      myPersistentData.instance.write(); // <-------------- this is an async operation
    }
    if (state == AppLifecycleState.resumed) {
      // came back to Foreground
    }
  }
```

This *seems* to work, but I'm concerned that the lifecycle could progress beyond "paused" (pause>stop>finish) so quickly that this "trailing" operation doesn't have time to finish... and thus the data would not be saved.

Is this a legitimate concern?

Comment: This is not just a concern but an actual problem I am facing. Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I would say as much as possible try to avoid calling async operations in the `dispose` or lifecycle methods of widgets, while you may be concerned that it may/may not complete i would recommend like the dart docs states here: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-async/unawaited.html, "Not all futures need to be awaited.", "You should use `unawaited` to convey the intention of deliberately not waiting for the future.". But generally, i'd avoid calling async functions in these methods.

Answer (score 0):

It should be a concern for sure because the time available for an app to run in background is limited and not defined.
Based on the memory resources needed for the most important app, **which is the one in foreground**, the system may kill your app faster or at a later point in time. In either scenarios you don't have much time to complete the tasks, this event should be used to do fast clean up like killing tasks that are started, clearing token or maybe saving a token or a session info.

There are also scenarios which will cause problems for this approach, like the pone runs out of battery or the OS crashes, in this case you don't have any notification of app going into bg. Or the user force quits your app.

In your case, I would say you have another concern, saving data in shared preferences shouldn't affect your UI only if:

- you save it synchronously which is a no no
- you save a huge chunk of data in shared prefs, in this case you should use a database.
- and a less likely scenario, you have a race condition while you save in shared prefs which are not thread safe.

I would suggest to rethink a bit your approach on this matter, maybe you can spawn async operations that save the data in certain points of the app (user exits a screen or whatever) while also keeping a copy in memory. Maybe is better to save it using a database. In the end is your decision, but my advice would be, don't rely on the app running in bg time.

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, there is no way you can continue a service purely in Flutter. That's bummer of course but there are work-arounds you can use to do that.

If you want to approach this problem in a more convenient but difficult way, you can always create a service in native (Kotlin/Java in case of Android or Swift/Objective-C for iOS) and call your native functions using [MethodChannels](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels). Your native service can be alive even if you kill your app. Think of Push-notifications service where even if you kill your app, Push service is always alive to serve your notification.